# Magento 2.2.4 : Different group dependency not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4, dependency, system-configuration

I'm using magento 2.2.4. In system configuration, I want to do apply dependency.

But, both groups and fields are different. It's working in same group. But, I can't get output for different group.

How to do it ? Please help me.

I added my system.xml file code :

> system.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="sectionID" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="200" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Name</label>
            <tab>TabName</tab>
            <resource>CompanyName_ModuleName::methodName</resource>
            <group id="groupID" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="fieldID" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="groupID2" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Form Configuration</label>
                <field id="fieldID2" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Check</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="fieldID">1</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only working if your field ID is under parent group ID. For apply dependency in other group, You need to add like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="sectionID" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="200" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Name</label>
            <tab>TabName</tab>
            <resource>CompanyName_ModuleName::methodName</resource>
            <group id="groupID" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="fieldID" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="groupID2" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Form Configuration</label>
                <field id="fieldID2" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Check</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="sectionID/groupID/fieldID">1</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Hope, It may be helpful for you. It should be working.

Comment: Happy Coding !! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue can be solved simply by mentioning the full path if the field is not in the current group. e.g.

```
<depends>
    <field id="section/group/field">1</field>
</depends>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: if used for group, it hides both groups.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a same group, you can use wildcard for field id as

```
<depends>
    <field id="*/*/[depends_on_field_id]">someValue</field>
</depends>
```

if it is a same section, you also allowed to use wildcard as

```
<depends>
    <field id="*/[other_group_id]/[depends_on_field_id]">someValue</field>
</depends>
```

so this could be enough in your case

```
<depends>
    <field id="*/groupID/fieldID">1</field>
</depends>
```